# How to assign multi dimensional array with key and values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm declaring a multi dimensional array with key and values at jquery but its showing error here is my code:

```
var beadArray = 
 {
    0: {
    barCode: "843036905884",
    build: "144",
    height: "46",
    image: "https://www.brighton.com/charmbuilder/beads/v144_qijc0272.png",
    mask: [
            0: ["3", "36"],
            1: ["1", "38"],
            2: ["1", "38"],
            3: ["1", "38"],
            4: ["1", "37"],
            5: ["1", "37"],
            6: ["1", "37"],
            7: ["2", "37"],
            8: ["1", "38"]        
          ],
    name: "Autumn Spirit Bead",
    quantity: "484",
    rX: "19",
    rY: "23",
    retail: "29",
    style: "jc0272",
    theme: "A-E-H-I-J-L",
    type: "B",
    width: "40"
  }
};
```

its showing

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 
>   at 0: ["3", "36"], line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant define values with index in arrays

```
var arr = [0:"1"];
```

you have to set the value in an array like below

```
var arr = ["1"];
```

and you can access is as

```
arr[0];
```

So in your case your syntax should be

```
var beadArray = 
 [
{
barCode: "843036905884",
build: "144",
height: "46",
image: "https://www.brighton.com/charmbuilder/beads/v144_qijc0272.png",
mask: [
         ["3", "36"],
         ["1", "38"],
         ["1", "38"],
         ["1", "38"],
         ["1", "37"],
         ["1", "37"],
         ["1", "37"],
         ["2", "37"],
         ["1", "38"]        
      ],
name: "Autumn Spirit Bead",
quantity: "484",
rX: "19",
rY: "23",
retail: "29",
style: "jc0272",
theme: "A-E-H-I-J-L",
type: "B",
width: "40"
  }
];
```

Comment: briliant its working for me thanks @soCalledDeveloper

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have associative arrays like for example the array monstrosity in PHP. It has arrays and it has object literals which are similar to hashes or dictionaries in other languages.

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) should be used when you want a list of values:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

[Object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) are used to map a key to a value:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

While you can use an integer as the key in an object literal its kind of pointless in this case as:

```
[
  ["3", "36"],
  ["1", "38"],
  ["1", "38"]
][1]
```

Will give the exact same result as:

```
{
    0: ["3", "36"],
    1: ["1", "38"],
    2: ["1", "38"]
}[1]
```